# successful test on amazon device farm fails when is run with jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Successful test on Amazon Device Farm fails when it is run with jenkins. Could someone tell me why is this happening, please? The error message given when the test is executed by Jenkins is "FBSSystemService] Sending request to open "com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunnerRunner"
Ipa and zip-with-dependencies.zip files are the same in both cases.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the device farm plugin for Jenkins you may also need to give an IAM policy to whatever entity Jenkins runs with for s3.  Device farm uses s3 in the sdk to store it's uploads which you can see if you try to upload something manually with the [create upload command](http://latest/reference/devicefarm/create). Using it the IAM policy [generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)

You can create a new policy with full access to device farm and the ability to do a putObject on the specific bucket from the create upload command.

Hope that helps